# On MCPE when you land on a block why does it crack

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

On MCPE when you land on a block why does it crack

Comment: I don't think that this question is unclear. If you don't understand it, please read the answer and it should be more clear. This question does stand on it's own, even without the answer, but the answer helps a bit with understanding the question.

Comment: I recommend that you edit this question to make it a bit easier to understand.

Answer (score 2):

Falling particles occur when you fall from a height that you would take fall damage from, and increase in quantity the higher you fall from.

They serve no purpose other than visually.